# Killing `sleep` in a subshell

Tags: bash, kill, subshell, sleep

In bash, I'm observing that calling `kill` on a sleeping process *won't*  kill it if I start out with a subshell. Can you help me understand why?

```bsh
function foo () {
  # Start a loop with `sleep` in the background
  while true; do
    >&2 echo looping
    sleep 5
  done &
  # Wait for user input, then kill the "sleep" loop
  loop_id=$!
  read -p 'press enter' DUMMY
  kill $loop_id
}

echo $(foo) # Call foo within a subshell
echo "DONE"
```

Two very different things can happen, depending on whether that last line uses a subshell

- With the subshell invocation `echo $(foo)`, if I press enter to satisfy the `read` call, then the script doesn't terminate until after the `sleep` concludes.
- If I invoke the function with just `foo` instead of `$(foo)`, then the script terminates as soon as I press enter.

I've really on this toy example, but in my real work, I want to capture stdout from `foo` into a shell variable, so I want to kill the subshell asap. Is there a way for me to achieve both parts of my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the command substitution `$(foo)`, the shell needs to wait until all input from the command substitution has been received. The `sleep` you're running has a copy of the file descriptor (probably a pipe) that's connected to where the shell reads the output of the command substitution. (I'm also pretty sure the `$!` will give the PID of the shell running the `while` loop, and not the `sleep` inside it.)

Consider e.g. this script:

```
foo() {
    sleep 5 &
    echo foo
}
tmp=$(foo)
echo end.
```

Running it takes 5 seconds.

But change the `sleep` line to `sleep 5 > /dev/null &`, and now the script returns immediately, because the `sleep` is no longer connected to the command substitution. Note that the backgrounded sleep will still be running there, in the background, until it times out. You're just not likely to notice it.

Note that that's specific to the *command substitution*, not just any subshell environment. (`(foo)` would also be a subshell, but should work similarly to `{ foo; }`, or just `foo` here.)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the thorough explanation and solution!